# Which physical remote controls work with android-tv?

Tags: remote-control, android-tv

I have an old ADT-1 dev kit laying around at home. I want to bring it back to life to use for Netflix and other streaming stuff.

It came with a game controller, which is fine for gaming, but not so convenient for TV.

What specifications should I look for to get a physical remote control? I searched AliExpress for "android tv remote" and got all kind of things, many using dongles.

Would any "bluetooth" controller work? I want to know what I should be looking for ...

Comment: Before buying stuff I would first evaluate if Netflix or your preferred streaming service really works in the preferred resolution on this device, because that a streaming service works may just mean you can get SD-TV resolution (no HD streaming)...

Comment: My Netflix subscription is SD. You have easy test for HD?

Comment: I probably will try popcorn time as well. I haven’t researched how yet